# Cosmos DB Pagination giving multiplied page records

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a scenario where I need to filter the collections based on the elements present in array inside documents. Can Anyone suggest how to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` with nested array in document

```
{
  "id": "abcd",
  "pqrs": 1,
  "xyz": "UNKNOWN_594",
  "arrayList": [
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "def": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 302,
      "def": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to filter and take 10 10 records from collections. I tried following query

```
SELECT * FROM collections c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.arrayList , {"Id":302 },true) or ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.arrayList , {"Id":2 },true)
ORDER BY c._ts DESC 
OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

Now when I run this query it is returning me 40 Records
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At every step in next OFFSET, RU will go on increasing, instead you can use ContinuationToken

```
        private static async Task QueryWithPagingAsync(Uri collectionUri)
        {
            // The .NET client automatically iterates through all the pages of query results 
            // Developers can explicitly control paging by creating an IDocumentQueryable 
            // using the IQueryable object, then by reading the ResponseContinuationToken values 
            // and passing them back as RequestContinuationToken in FeedOptions.

            List<Family> families = new List<Family>();

            // tell server we only want 1 record
            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };

            // using AsDocumentQuery you get access to whether or not the query HasMoreResults
            // If it does, just call ExecuteNextAsync until there are no more results
            // No need to supply a continuation token here as the server keeps track of progress
            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionUri, options).AsDocumentQuery();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (Family family in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
                {
                    families.Add(family);
                }
            }

            // The above sample works fine whilst in a loop as above, but 
            // what if you load a page of 1 record and then in a different 
            // Session at a later stage want to continue from where you were?
            // well, now you need to capture the continuation token 
            // and use it on subsequent queries

            query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(
                collectionUri,
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }).AsDocumentQuery();

            var feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Family>();
            string continuation = feedResponse.ResponseContinuation;

            foreach (var f in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(f => f.Id))
            {
               
            }

            // Now the second time around use the contiuation token you got
            // and start the process from that point
            query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(
                collectionUri,
                new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = 1,
                    RequestContinuation = continuation,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                }).AsDocumentQuery();

            feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Family>();

            foreach (var f in feedResponse.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(f => f.Id))
            {
               
            }
        }
```

To skip through specific page, pfb the code

```
private static async Task QueryPageByPage(int currentPageNumber = 1, int documentNumber = 1)
    {
        // Number of documents per page
        const int PAGE_SIZE = 3 // configurable;

      

        // Continuation token for subsequent queries (NULL for the very first request/page)
        string continuationToken = null;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"----- PAGE {currentPageNumber} -----");

            // Loads ALL documents for the current page
            KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Family>> currentPage = await QueryDocumentsByPage(currentPageNumber, PAGE_SIZE, continuationToken);

            foreach (Family celeryTask in currentPage.Value)
            {
               
                documentNumber++;
            }

            // Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next page query execution
            continuationToken = currentPage.Key;
            currentPageNumber++;
        } while (continuationToken != null);

        Console.WriteLine("\n--- END: Finished Querying ALL Dcuments ---");
    }
```

and QueryDocumentsByPage function as follows

```
    private static async Task<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Family>>> QueryDocumentsByPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string continuationToken)
    {
        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://{CosmosDB/SQL Account Name}.documents.azure.com:443/"), "{CosmosDB/SQL Account Key}");

        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions {
            MaxItemCount = pageSize,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,

            // IMPORTANT: Set the continuation token (NULL for the first ever request/page)
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken 
        };

        IQueryable<Family> filter = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>("dbs/{Database Name}/colls/{Collection Name}", feedOptions);
        IDocumentQuery<Family> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();

        FeedResponse<Family> feedRespose = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Family>();

        List<Family> documents = new List<Family>();
        foreach (CeleryTask t in feedRespose)
        {
            documents.Add(t);
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Ensure the continuation token is kept for the next requests
        return new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Family>>(feedRespose.ResponseContinuation, documents);
    }
```

Comment: When we use continuous token. Lets suppose we need to go to 10th page then we need to run this query 10 times with this approach. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: no, I have edited answer and added another code just to skip through specific page

Comment: I am assuming `QueryDocumentsByPage` as the first method name. am I correct ?

Comment: pardon, i missed to add QueryDocumentsByPage function, now added

Comment: `Do{...}While()` going into infinite loop. Please suggest

Comment: try to check if there are records in currentPage.Value, if not then break ? please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236680/discussion-between-sarang-kulkarni-and-ameya-deshpande).

Comment: This solution is not exactly working. It will be doing round trip for all the pages to skip. So half solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually receiving 40 elements in the results? Or is it  that you are getting back 10 documents but maybe your Cosmos itself has 40 documents for this query?

Using ORDER by clause retrieves all the documents based on the query, orders it in the DB and then applies the OFFSET and LIMIT values to deliver the final results.

I've illustrated this from the below snapshot.

- My Cosmos account has 14 documents which match the query, this is
  what matches the retrieved document count.
- The output document is 10 because the DB had to skip the first 5 and
  then deliver the next 5.
- But my actual results are only 5 documents because that is what I
  asked for.

[image]

Continuation tokens are efficient for paging but have limitations. They cannot be used if you directly want to skip pages(say jump from page 1 to page 10). You need to traverse through the pages from the first document and keep using the token to go to the next page. Due to the limitations, it is usually recommended if you have a large number of documents for a single query.

Another recommendation is to use indexing to improve your RU/s usage when using ORDER BY. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#order-by-queries-on-multiple-properties).